# Trying to rename files using two txt files but not getting the right results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

recently just tried to write a script so I could rename multiple files from two txt files in correct order, it kinda works but not getting the results I'm looking for.

If anyone can see what's wrong with this please let me know!

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat ../temp/files.txt); for j in $(cat ../temp/filenames.txt); do mv $i $j; done
```

Comment: Well at least there is can be files with spaces, so it will not work, you need use `"$i"` and `"$j"`. And even than it will not work because. `for j` will be cycled for each `i`

Comment: Any idea on how to resolve that?

Comment: Yep, have no console near me. But I suggest `for i from 1 to "source file lines count" than `mv \`head -n $i "src_filename"|tail -1\` \`head -n $i "dst_filename"|tail -1\``

Comment: So idea use cycle thru numbers and use $i as line number in file

Comment: Read each file into an array, then walk the array index.

Comment: [how to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). `; for` is missing a `do`. The code is strange - you are iterating over one file then foreach iterating over foreach line in second file... Could you post sample like 5 lines of content of `files.txt` and `filenames.txt` files and post the `mv` commands that should be executed?

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -n` for any sort of bulk/automated move/rename operation. Without the `-i` or `-n` option, `mv` will silently and irreversibly delete files if there's a name conflict (or mistake like in the original that renames *all* input files to the same name -- without `-i` or `-n`, that'll delete all but the last file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both files have exactly the same number of lines (each line representing a filename), and filenames don't contain a new-line nor a tab character, a quick-and-dirty bash solution (using the `paste` utility) could be:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r from to; do
    echo mv "$from" "$to"
done < <(paste from.txt to.txt)
```

Remove the `echo` after testing and making sure it will work as intended.

Answer (score 4):

You have parallel files so you'll want to read from the two files at the same time in one loop rather than having nested loops. When you have nested loops you're going to end up reading the second file over and over, once for every single line in the first file. A single loop that reads from both files will march through them in lockstep.

```
while IFS= read -u3 -r source && IFS= read -u4 -r target; do
    mv "$source" "$target"
done 3<../temp/files.txt 4<../temp/filenames.txt
```

Steps:

1. The part after the `done` is actually executed first. It opens `../temp/files.txt` on file descriptor `3` and `../temp/files.txt` on file descriptor `4`.
2. The `while` loop reads one line from each file and, thanks to `&&`, stops as soon as either file hits EOF.

   1. `read -u3 source` reads from FD 3 into a variable `$source`.
   2. `read -u4 target` reads from FD 4 into a variable `$target`.
   3. `IFS=` and `-r` are extra careful options to disable all input mangling. Specifically, `IFS=` tells `read` not to strip leading whitespace and `-r` tells it to leave backslashes alone.
3. Call `mv` every time we get a line from both files.

Answer (score 0):

So again, have no console, but seems to be working

```
for i in $(seq 1 `wc -l ../temp/files.txt|cut -f 1 -d" "`); do
    mv "`head -n $i ../temp/files.txt|tail -1`" "`head -n $i ../temp/filenames.txt|tail -1`"
done
```

Comment: Make sure you do a backup before run it on working machine.